# Fuel line connector disconnected while driving

Tags: fuel-system, leak, renault, connector, clio

Car: clio 1.2 43kw, 2000, d7f engine, 8v

Car was difficult to start and while driving it lost power. I parked it in the city.
The fuel line connector to the fuel injector rail disconnected and the gasoline was leaking all over.

It was dark and my phone battery was bad so I didn't figure it out how to secure it together. I can put it together, but it is not secure, or I don't know how. I find it odd, because sensors have some safety, that they just don't disconnect on their own. What do you think is the fuel connector damaged and that is the reason or why. It disconnects too easily. Please if anyone can help I will be grateful!

[image: Fuel line connector]

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but it would seem to me either the connection tab on the fuel rail has busted or the connector on the fuel line is bad. Once you figure out which is happening, it'll tell you what direction you need to go. As it looks right now, I can see two o-rings. Both of those need to be inserted into your fuel rail for them to be right. If you can bet both in, it might just be that is why it's not connecting properly (not in the proper place).

Answer (score 1):

Thx Paulster!

The issue is solved. 2 teeth on the outer plastic ring didn't held and the connector disconnected. I needed to press the connector a little more to get them in. Spare part is hard to get for this old car, so I just added small clamp to compress 2 teeth on the safe side. I think it is enough.

[image]